# vim highlight syntax issue

Tags: vim, syntax, colors

I really struggle to understand this.
On my MAC with vim version 7.3 I can enjoy the 256 color scheme while on my unix machine with vim version 7.0.237 I cannot.
I have checked all the steps described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_setup_for_console_Vim) but still no results. Is it just a matter of the different versions of vim I am using?

EDIT:
Extra checks I have made: when running

```
vim --version | grep syntax
```

I get different outputs for the two terminal. Locally, where the syntax works, I get

```
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
```

whereas on my unix machine to which I ssh I get

```
-sniff +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static
```

Another detail is that I do get syntax in both the windows, the only difference is that locally I get all the colours while from ssh I only get few of them (and yes syntax is on since they share the same .vimrc file)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your (very) old Vim *may* be built without support for syntax highlighting. Try the following command in your shell:

```
$ vim --version | grep syntax
```

If there's a `-syntax` in the output you don't have syntax highligting built in and you'll need to build Vim yourself or use your package manager. 7.0 is *very* old, you might want to grab the latest version, 7.4, or at least 7.3.

If there's a `+syntax`, the problem is elsewhere: you didn't do `:syntax on` or your terminal emulator is not setup correctly or anything… Please give us more details about your setup.

Comment: I have added the details, what else would you like to know? Thanks